# Internet explorer <video> change source

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm setting the source of a  tag with javascript:

```
$("#video-player").attr("src", '/DownloadCenter/GetFile?path=' + file.Path);
```

Setting the source the first time is no problem, but if I use the same snippet causes the following error:

> invalid source

Has somebody experience with changig the source of the video tag?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that the path you are setting is definitely correct? e.g. `'/DownloadCenter/GetFile?path=' + file.Path` definitely points to a valid video file`?

You could try and not use jQuery at all:

```
document.getElementById("video-player").src = "pathToVideoFile.mp4";
```

**EDIT!**

Try setting the server's MIME types for video by adding the following to the .htaccess file:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Comment: Yes the source is definitivly correct. With Chrome and Firefox everything works in this way

Comment: And is the file an MP4 file?

Comment: You might need to set the server's MIME type and ensure that it's set to video/mp4 for mp4 files. Sometimes IE can be really picky about that. I have written how to set this in the answer above.

Comment: I think it isn't an server-side problem. Because setting the source the first time is no problem, but if the code is executed the next time, the source seems to be invalid, even if the source is exactly the same.

Comment: Hae you tried calling .load() after changing the src? e.g. document.getElementById("video-player").load();

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is on the server:

```
byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
return File(content, "application/octet-stream", file.Name);
```

It has to be:

```
return File(content, "video/mp4", file.Name);
```

But I still wounder why it works when setting the source the first time..